# How to Write strings on Bitmap Image wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, bitmapimage

I already searched the whole internet on doing this but no luck,
I know there is a class called `WritableBitmap` , But i don't know how to use it to Write strings.

One approach i tried is to make a normal `Bitmap` object and use `Graphics` on it insted of WritableBitmap .

I want to make like a banner generator and give it to the user to save it ,But i have no idea.

thanks.

Comment: So drawing on the image and making a new image of that did not work?

Comment: it worked but is there any way to do it with a Writable Bitmap ?

Comment: It does not look like that was the intention for the `WriteableBitmap`.

Comment: ok then,i will use the DrawingContext class

Comment: You searched the **WHOLE** internet? Jeez, how long have you been working on this? :D

Comment: for a lifeless person like me i don't really count xd